# Css transition affects layout height

Tags: css, scrollbar, css-transitions, css-animations

1. Take a look at the example at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HpbLo).
2. Minimize bottom area so that scrollbar appears on the right.
3. Hover over links and enjoy bouncing scrollbar.

The problem appears in all browsers. Why is this happening? Is there any way to fix this without "overflow-y: hidden"?

Comment: Fixed the issue by wrapping each button in a container with padding and overflow:hidden. Here's the working example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/csgJr
Though I think there is a better solution, maybe it helps someone.

Comment: For future reference, you should include the *relevant* code in the question itself because links don't always last